# Error testing connection : java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:37965

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, cicd

I have installed Kind for local Kubernetes deployment. I want to make a connection with Jenkins using the kube config file as a secret in Jenkins cloud but getting an error on `Test Connection` `Error testing connection : java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:37965`

`kubectl config view`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:37965
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

`cat ~.kube/config`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://127.0.0.1:37965
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: 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
```

`kind get kubeconfig --internal`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://kind-control-plane:6443
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: 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
```

I have a master node with a kind

```
kind get clusters
kind
```

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   18h   v1.21.1
```

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:37965
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:37965/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

What could be the issue, I'm not able find the solution and i'm trying this for the last one days and I did not get the proper solution.

Comment: Can you try by changing the 127.0.0.1 with the Local kubernetes IP in which you deployed or change the IP 127.0.0.1 to <local deployment K8’s IP\> to access the port 37965 and  Have a try.

Comment: Thanks, @HemanthKumar for replying to me. are you talking about the port-forward way with the config server of the deployment expose service targetPort?
Can you please explain a bit more about how can I get a Local Kubernetes IP?

Comment: I'm confused as to why the Kind cluster config giving localhost however I used minikube in this minikube-provided IP and it worked but I want to create a multi-node cluster so I'm using Kind(Kubernetes in Docker) but got this issue and I'm unable to resolve this